# What is the opposite of "had to"?

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

"Had to" is the past tense of "have to," referring to a past obligation. Negating it to "didn't have to" doesn't give me the opposite meaning. I know that we can use "mustn't" as an opposite to "have to" in the present, but I don't know what the equivalent would be in the past.

Comment: It's probably not acceptable to some people but I would say that the opposite of "to have to" is actually "to have to not". It's clumsy but I've certainly found myself using it and I have heard other people using it too (in the UK). For example I might say "You **have to not click** on the browser icon before the wifi connection is established, otherwise it will hang and take forever to sort itself out"

Answer (score 1):

"Opposite" is not a very precise word; there are famously many [types of opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition).

*Had to* is, as you say, the past tense of *have to*, which is a periphrastic modal auxiliary.
I.e, it's a phrase that means the same as *must*, a modal auxiliary verb, but has a past tense form. That comes in handy (you can't say **I musted go yesterday*, after all), but it's also nice to have some flexible ways to express negation.
Modals of all sorts interact with negatives in complex ways.
Note that

- *You must go*  means that you have an obligation to go,
  while
- *You must not go* means you have an obligation **not** to go.

On the other hand,

- *You have to go* also means you have an obligation to go (*have to = must*, here)
  **but**
- *You don't have to go* means you have **no** obligation to go (*have to ≠ must* here)

[Logically](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) this is the difference between

- `Necessary (Not (Go (You)))`  *You must not go*
  and
- `Not (Necessary (Go (You)))`  *You don't have to go*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I express mustn't in the past tense?

Comment: 'Were not', or 'weren't to'.... In following the directions, it appeared they were not to use the present tense, but the past.

Comment: What do you mean? Not Necessary, or Necessary Not?